# Computational statistics book

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references, computational-statistics

Can anybody recommend me a good book on Computational Statistics? I am new to this subject so I am not sure how to be more specific.

Comment: This is a broad question, can you be more specific towards what you are looking for?

Comment: What aspects of computational statistics? It's a very broad area.

Answer (score 3):

This question is probably going to get closed for being off topic, but here's one:

> Givens, GH and Hoeting, JA. [Computational Statistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470533315), 2nd ed. Wiley (2012)

You might also like [The Elements of 
Statistical Learning](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) (Hastie, Tibshirani, and Friedman; available online as PDF).

Comment: *Elements of Statistical Computing* (R.A. Thisted, Chapman and Hall, 1988) is older, yet it contains interesting material, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

I've found Monahan's [Numerical Methods of Statistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521139511) very valuable. I also have Computational Statistics by Givens and Hoeting, and [Numerical Methods of Statistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441959440) by Lange, both of which are good. [Statistical Computing with R](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584885459) by Rizzo is nice to have if you're wanting to do a lot of this stuff in R.  I find myself jumping around a lot, and still doing a lot of reading outside for things like quadrature, matrix computations, and everything in Press et al.

Comment: I like Statistical Computing with R as a very applied example based book.  Highly recommended.